# ALSA (snd_pcm_open) over SSH?

Tags: ssh, alsa

I have written an application using ALSA (snd_pcm_open, snd_pcm_readi, etc). The application works perfect locally on my machine. However, when I SSH to another machine and run it through the SSH connection, all calls to snd_pcm_open fails with a message "Device does not exist" or similar. The remote machine has a soundcard just as my local machine has.

What could be the problem here?

Thanks!

EDIT: If I run the application using the console on the remote computer (walk to the computer, login, run the application), the application runs fine.

Comment: You want the audio to play on the remote machine, correct? And the remote machine also uses alsa, and it is properly configured?

Comment: Yes. Actually, my application records audio, but that shouldn't make any difference, right? The remote machine also uses ALSA, yes. If I run my application locally on the remote machine (walk to the computer, login, start my application) it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason. Turns out `/dev/audio` and the devices below `/dev/snd/` where all owned by the user logged in on the remote computer, and readable/writable by no one else. For testing I applied `chmod 777 /dev/audio /dev/snd/*` and it started working.

Anyone know how I can apply a bit more generous permissions to the audio devices for the remote computer (which will last after a reboot)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be with `/dev/snd/*` access rights.
Be sure the user is in the audio group.
In my case, I had to do `adduser $USER audio`, disconnect and then reconnect.

Answer (score 1):

Just to check for the obvious: Are the drivers for the sound card on the remote machine loaded and working correctly? Check `/proc/asound/cards` and see so that the card is listed.

Comment: Yes, everything is working correctly on the remote machine. See my edit to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm...you have the application installed on the remote machine and the remote machine has otherwise working aplay etc?  The remote machine must be set up so that if you were to login from the console and run the application, it would work

If this is the case then check your environment variables as sometimes they can be subtly different.

Comment: If I run my application locally on the remote machine (walk to the remote computer, login, start my application) it works. So if I run from the console, it works. If I run over SSH, snd_pcm_open fails. Should have written that in the question, sorry.

Comment: to check your environment variables do `env > walklogin.txt` and `env > sshlogin.txt` when logged on under the two different conditions.  Then `diff sshlogin.txt walklogin.txt` and see what the differences are

Comment: I did that, and there are some differences but I can't see anything that would interfere with audio or audio recording. What should I be looking for?

Comment: libraries and paths are your first stop if there are no obvious "SOUNDSETTING" kind of variables